# What is the difference between "to seek" and "to seek out"?

Tags: verbs, differences

I have used both "seek" and "seek out" more or less interchangeably, but is there any structural or logical difference between the two?

Comment: seek out is more specific than seek

Comment: I should think it depends on how much rootling about is involved.

Comment: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/seek claims that "seek out" means to search for and find something, while "seek" just means to search for something. But the examples they give don't really support the distinction.

Comment: Have a look at definition 1.3 in [this dictionary reference](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seek). Please note that "Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic." For that reason, I've voted to close for lack of research.